Unity HDRP/Lit Material with alphaCutoff not rendering from AssetBundle
Hello i am scratching my head and could use some help in understanding this problem:
I have two Unity HDRP Projects with equal render settings.
Project A is used to create enviournments for project B that consumes them using an exported AssetBundle from A. Until recently this worked like a charm but since we updated our tree materials to use the HDRP/Lit Shader with alpha cutoff enabled there are problems with these materials.
If i load my test scene within the editor of project B, everything looks fine:

The small cube is placed in the loading scene of project B, the tree and larger cube are objects placed in the scene from project A and are loaded via the asset bundle.
All objects have the HDRP/Lit Shader and the alphaCutoff enabled.
The issue occurs if i build the application (project B). If i load my scene there it looks like this:

Logging the material and renderer properties reveals no difference between build and editor.
If i exchange the material of the large cube and the leaves to use the material of the small cube as i load the scene :
    var roots = scene.GetRootGameObjects();
    var template = Resources.Load<Material>("LitTemplate");
    foreach( var root in roots )
    {
        var renderers = root.GetComponentsInChildren<MeshRenderer>();
        foreach(var renderer in renderers)
        {
            var materials = new List<Material>();
            for (var i = 0; i < renderer.materials.Length; i++)
            {
                var material = renderer.materials[i];
                var cutoffEnabled = material.GetFloat("_AlphaCutoffEnable");
                if(cutoffEnabled < 1f)
                {
                    materials.Add(material);
                    continue;
                }
                materials.Add(template);       
            }
            renderer.SetMaterials(materials);
        }
    }

The result is as expected in the editor but not in the build.


Can you point me to the right direction where to look ?
